# Windows Phone: How do I keep ScrollViewer totally disabled until explicitly re-enabling it

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

My issue is that I have a very simple Listbox with a list of items. I noticed that when I disable the ScrollViewer from the MainPage_Loaded event, the ScrollViewer can be re-enabled by swiping the Listbox diagonally at any direction.

I have tried setting the property from XAML:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...../>
```

I also tried to do it from code:

```
var myScrollviewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyListBox, 0) as ScrollViewer;
myScrollviewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
myScrollviewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

Straight vertical and horizontal swipe do indicate that the ScrollViewer is disabled but when I swipe diagonally without lifting my hand from the screen, the items in the listbox start scrolling up and down. This behavior seems like a bug!

Can someone tell me how to totally disable the scrollviewer so diagonal swiping doesn't temporarily re-enable the scrollviewer?

This behavior is affecting my underline task of dragging an item while the scrollviewer is disabled.

Thanks

Comment: Why use a ListBox if you do not want to scroll? You should use an ItemsControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's interesting, haven't noticed that before. It may be a bug but to get around it try setting the ScrollViewer's [ManipulationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.manipulationmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to `Control` to let the OS know that you'll be handling the ScrollViewer at the control level rather than letting the system handle it.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" .../>
```

However, when you re-enable it, set the `ManipulationMode` back to `System` for a smoother scrolling.

**Update based on comments**

To re-enable the scrollviewer, do this

```
var myScrollviewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyListBox, 0) as ScrollViewer;
myScrollviewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
myScrollviewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
//key part - use SetValue to set ManipluationMode.System/Control
myScrollviewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.System);
```

If you need to disable it again, you can do the same thing but with the disabled properties and `ManipulationMode.Control`.

```
var myScrollviewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyListBox, 0) as ScrollViewer;
myScrollviewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
myScrollviewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
//key part - use SetValue to set ManipluationMode.System/Control
myScrollviewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.Control);
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the prompt reply KeyboardP. I tried that already and it didn't help. I am still able to temporarily re-enable it by diagonal swiping. It's a really weird behavior.

Comment: I can reproduce the error (I'm running on WP8 emulator with a WP7 project). However, setting `Control` fixes it (whilst also keeping the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` properties as well). That's quite strange.

Comment: It appears we can't really change the ManipulationMode in runtime because I get an error while switching back to "system".

Comment: @user1058145 - What's the error message? I'll see if I can repro.

Comment: <code>{System.InvalidOperationException: ManipulationMode has already been set and cannot be changed after OnApplyTemplate.
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.set_ManipulationMode(ManipulationMode value)
   at PhoneApp4.MainPage.myImage_ManipulationStarted(Object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)}<code>

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out a workaround. Feel free to unmark this as an answer incase someone else has one that fixes both issues.

Comment: @keyboardP I have a ScrollViewer with a similar problem. I used your method and it works great. My problem is that I want to manipulate an object in the scrollviewer, when it is "disabled". But when I do this it lacks quite a lot. Which I think is because of setting the scrollviewer to control ? I can open a new question. But since it is so specific I wanted to hear if you had an idea and/or wanted to help+